# matplotlib - plt.figure() freezes

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.3

I have function that renders some plot and then saves it to png file. Simplified code:

```
def render_plot(self, parameter1, parameter2):

    dates = get_my_dates()
    values = get_my_values()
    fig = plt.figure() # freezes here when calling render_plot for the 2nd or 3rd time!
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    ... # performing some calculations and drawing plots

    ax.plot_date(dates, values, '-', marker='o')

    plt.savefig("media/plot.png")
    plt.cla()
    plt.clf()
    plt.close()
```

Function freezes at line "fig = plt.figure()" (100% CPU usage - infinite loop?)  but only when calling function 2nd or 3rd time, works fine for the first time and rendering good looking plot. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

fig = plt.figure() will cause the freeze for my PyQt5 as well.

I don't exactly know the reasons, but I have found a nice workaround that works for me.

Workaround:
from matplotlib. Figure import Figure
fig1 = Figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot()

Answer (score -1):

This is probably not the reason but first, you do not need

```
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
```

Try just

```
ax = plt.gca()
```

Then, comment

```
plt.close()
```

It may help. Just a guess.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not helping.. Still freezing.